# Derive Rodrigues' formula for Chebyshev Polynomials from Chebyshev DE

Tags: special-functions, chebyshev-polynomials

I'm trying to derive Rodrigues' formula for Chebyshev Polynomials, by using Chebyshev DE
$$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+n^2y=0. \quad \quad (1)$$
Rodrigues' formula for Chebyshev Polynomials is
$$T_n(x)=(-1)^n2^n\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2}$$
The problem has been addressed also in [Derive the Rodrigues' formula for Chebyshev Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965433/derive-the-rodrigues-formula-for-chebyshev-polynomials/3965703?noredirect=1#comment9060298_3965703) with a different solution. Unfortunately, I can't explain why, replacing in (1) $y$ by $\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2}$ don't obtain an identity. In fact, if I set, in (1),
$$y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2}$$
I obtain
$$\sqrt{1 - x^2} \left[(-1 + n^2) \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2} - 3 x \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2} + (1 - x^2) \frac{d^{n+2}}{dx^{n+2}}(1-x^2)^{n-1/2} \right]=0$$
which is not an identity.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960306/deriving-rodrigues-formula

Comment: @Chee Han: thank you! I read the post but in my case I have also a function that mulplies the multiple derivatives.